# Algorithms to securely derive symmetric keys

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, openssl

I need to  derive symmetric keys between two communication endpoints on an embedded device with 800MHz ARM core. What algorithms are available to have this secure key derivation mechanism?

I know Diffie-Hellman is one of them, but I am unable to make the right choice while considering computational requirement vs security. It seems there are many variants available, and parameters involved. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer but for key exchange (KEX) you want Diffie-Hellman-Merkle over elliptic curves (aka ECDHE) as it is common practice these days and is as light as it can get. As for authentication during the KEX, you can also use elliptic curves (i.e. Ed25519).

Comment: If you need to choose a curve and Ed25519 is not available then choose a named curve over $F(p)$ such as `P-384` or `brainpoolP320r1`.

Comment: You mean *Key exchange* and not *key derivation*, correct?

Comment: @mat Well, if we're nitpicking, the key is not really exchanged either. NIST calls it key *establishment*. Key derivation is usually part of that as generally a KDF is used after the master secret has been established.